# Call a directive for each time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to call an angular directive. That should call for each time and before all events `eg:- ng-click..etc`. when view value changed.and it should be the first call when view chaged.

Here is the [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/61/)

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
  .module('myApp').directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { 
        val : '=val'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            if (!ctrl) return;
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {

            if(attrs.symbol == '$')
             return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue, '$')
             else
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });
            elem.bind('change', function(event) {

            var a = elem.val();            
            var plainNumber = a.split('.').filter(function(e){
                return (e.length > 0);            
            }).join('.');
            var i = 0;
            if(isNaN(parseFloat(plainNumber))){
            i = (attrs.symbol == '$') ? 1 : 3;
            }
            var num = plainNumber.substring(i, plainNumber.length).replace(/,/g,'');
            if(attrs.symbol == '$')
            elem.val($filter('currency')(num, attrs.symbol));
            else
              elem.val($filter('currency')(num));                
            var n =parseFloat(num);
            scope.val = Number(n);
            if(!scope.$$phase) {
                scope.$apply();
             }
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

How can I call a directive for each time.

Comment: I would recommend you to read this: https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: you can `$watch` your value in `link` function of your directive and recompile the directive on change?

Comment: @BaluKrish https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/69/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that on `change` of value, you can `$watch` on it inside your `link` function of directive. It watches your value and gives you callback when it changes. Like this:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return elem.val()
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    var a = newVal;
    // what you do on blur, do it here 
})
```

Here's the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/69/)